# Codeigniter, is it possible to have a public function name that is variable?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm continuing to develop my website in CodeIgniter framework and I'm really happy for the choice I've done because it's very easy and the code is clean.
Below I'll explain my current issue.

In one of my Controllers I've written:

```
public function abcd() {
   //CONTENT of the controller public function      
}
```

Is it possible to dinamically change the "abcd()" name taking the value, for example, from mySQL?
Just to be more clear, I would like to use a statement the allows me to use always the same CONTENT of the controller, but for different public functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the controller function name with ROUTE in config/routes.php

```
$route['dynamic_name'] = "controller_name/abcd";
```

where ever you change the route name, the controller in the url will change

before

```
http://domain.name/index.php/welcome/abcd
```

after

```
http://domain.name/index.php/welcome/dynamic_name
```

also can add multiple route for same_url

and if you want to get value from db use below code in config/routes.php

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get('menus');
$names = $query->result();

foreach ($names as $key => $name) { 
$route[$name] = "controller_name/abcd";
}
```

Comment: you cannot change the controller name dynamic in controller file

Comment: Thanks Parthiban K for your reply. I've done as you suggested in the first part of your reply (I've to try the part with DB inclusion) but if I put in the route.php only $route['dynamic_name'] the script gives me a 404 error. Instead, if I use $route['controller_name/dynamic_name'] it works.

Comment: Considering this, if I should update the DB code...how will it become? Is it correct to update the $route in the following way? => $route['controller_name/'.$name]

Comment: Just refer the below link https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Dear Parthiban, no I didn'solve my issue. If I try to implement the database solution as you suggested, I receive a 500 error.

Comment: In the routes.php I've written: `require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get('namestocks');
$names = $query->result();

foreach ($names as $key => $name) { 
$route[$name] = "nasdaq/overview";
}`

Comment: I've created the database mysql: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `namestocks` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `stocks` varchar(192) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `stocks` (`stocks`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

Comment: I've inserted a value in the table: INSERT INTO `namestocks` (`id`, `stocks`) VALUES ('1', 'absol');

Comment: In my controller Nasdaq I've created a method as below:   public function overview() {
         
   $this->load->view('templates/header_no_login', $data);
   
   $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  }

Comment: If I digit -> localhost/nasdaq/absol -> I receive a 500 error

Comment: Is nasdaq/ is controller name or project name Please tell me

Comment: i hope nasdaq is the controller name when $route['absol'] is rewriting the url you provide the whole nasdaq/overview is converted into absol so nasdaq is not working, now try  **http://localhost/absol**, reply me if not works

Comment: Nasdaq is the controller. I've written localhost/absol and it doesn't work. :(

Comment: oh my friend! I've finally found a solution... trying some modifies on the code now it works. This is the code "require_once(BASEPATH.'database/DB.php');
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get('namestocks');
$names = $query->result();
foreach ($names as $row) { 
$route['nasdaq/'.$row->stocks] = "nasdaq/overview";
}"